# Python DataFrame find values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I've DataFrame like this:

```
5 1 89107633648 19239.9
6 nan  9348.62
7 nan  3191.83
8 nan  2962.06
9 nan  3737.39
10 2 9156559561 6318.99
11 nan  2138.27
12 nan  1933.3
13 nan  2247.42
14 3 9107812806 25324.19
15 nan  1169.1
16 nan  3750.52
17 nan  3436.4
18 nan  5140.16
19 nan  nan
20 nan  3196.79
21 nan  2985.62
22 nan  2869.01
23 nan  2776.59
```

I need to get a two-dimensional list grouped by nan field.
`[[9348.62, 3191.83, 2962.06, 3737.39],  [2138.27, 1933.3, 2247.42], ...]`
How can I do that?

```
n_rows = res.astype(bool).sum(axis=0)['Unnamed: 5']
rows_3 = [[] for i in range(n_rows)]

for i in range(0, len(res)):
    tmp = 0
    j =0 
    if res.iloc[i]['Unnamed: 5'] is '':
        tmp = res.iloc[i][12]
    else:
       j += 1
    rows_3[j].append(tmp)
    tmp =0
    
print(rows_3)
```

Comment: Hi for what do you need the list, would it viable to group the dataframe ?

Comment: Find the median by these values

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, using [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) with `ffill` then `GroupBy` followed by list splice.

```
# renamed columns for convenience
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

print(
    df.assign(col2 = df.col2.fillna(method='ffill'))
        .groupby('col2')['col3'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist()[1:])
        .reset_index(drop=True).tolist()
)
```

Comment: I get it 


0      [9348.62, 3191.83, 2962.06, 3737.39, 74072.11,...
1      [872.66, 1686.78, 1593.82, 1439.76, 1082.5, 96...
2      [313.28, 1252.88, 1263.67, 1263.67, 1271.47, 1...
3      [5022.6, 4056.01, 4056.01, 4056.01, 4056.01, 4...
4      [4561.93, 5438.07, 5438.07, 67206.1, 1334.14, ...
                             ...                        
605    [708.56, 785.5, 785.5, 229.14, 782.7, 796.34, ...
606    [335.23, 1364.34, 1285.62, 1505.49, 12595.32, ...
607    [1242.32, 3177.49, 3580.19, 2777.93, 9277.4, 1...

Comment: @Mihail, If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).